# Suid binary executes shell, but I still have the old permissions

Tags: busybox, ctf

Currently doing a ctf challenge where a kernel image and a `initramfs.cpio.gz` were provided, running their `run.sh` results in a `busybox` environement.

So there's a binary that has it's `suid` bit set:

`-rwsr-xr-x    1 root     root          8752 Feb  6 09:26 target`

And I manage to get it to drop a shell by using making it call `execve("/bin/sh", argv=["/bin/sh"], envp=NULL)`. I won't get into the details here as it is pretty long.
I had to provide `argv=["/bin/sh"]` since `bin/sh` is actually just a link to `busybox`.

The point is that the binary actually spawns a shell, but I still have the old priviliges and not root priviliges. How is this possible when the shell runs under the `root` binary? Is there something I am missing? Any suggestions will be appreciated.